# How do you send text to Firefox developer console using selenium

Tags: python, firefox, selenium

Using Selenium (python) I'm attempting to send text (example: JSON payload) to the Firefox console and not having any luck.

Basically something like send_keys("data") that sends to the console in Firefox.

Comment: May I ask why you're trying to send data to the console? It's my understanding that Selenium is designed to test user interaction with a site so hopefully your average user is not opening up the Firefox console to do things. Also, this question may be better suited to [the QA StackExchange Site](http://sqa.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I'm testing a Unity driven app and dev has opened it up so I can send camera locations via JSON format (XYZ).  They can be entered into Firefox (or Chrome) console.